# Initiating comms to an embedded 3G device

Tags: sockets, tcp, arduino, gsm, 3g

I have an Arduino based device interfaced to a 3G modem which I use to record data from several sensors in a remote environment. I would like to be able to send commands and stream some data from the device every now and then back to my standard network connected PC. If the remote device was connected to a WIFI or other local area network this would be relatively straightforward, but as the device connects over 3G this means that it is behind the 3G carriers NAT and so establishing a connection to the device becomes difficult.
The device can, of course, open a TCP connection to my host PC any time it wishes, the problem is telling the device when i want it to do so. I need some way of getting some kind of message to the device to notify it that I would like it to initiate a connection to my PC.

I've been reading up on NAT traversal techniques that app developers use to initiate P2P comms between 2 devices both behind NATs such as UDP and TCP 'hole punching' but this method seems rather too complex for my arduino system. Another general idea is to have the device polling a web server periodically looking for a signal to initiate a connection, but I'm not sure how much traffic (and data usage costs) this would generate as the device would have to poll every 10 seconds or so in order to make sure it initiates it's connection within a reasonable time frame of the request being set on the web server that it polls.

Is there any commonly used method of achieving something like this? Any general ideas or insight would be much appreciated

Thanks,
     James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution will depend largely on your particular applications and requirements.

There are several ways to achieve this type of functionality and it looks like you have covered some of them already. The most common are:

- have the device poll the server. This may be ok depending on the response times you need. If you need to poll as regularly as you suggest above then I imagine power may be more important to you than data rates, especially if you are battery connected. With a typical 3G data plan the polling itself will have a negligible data overhead, I would think.
- have the server send a SMS which then triggers the device to contact the server. You need to make sure the SMS variable delivery time is ok for you and you also have to be aware that SMS delivery is not guaranteed so you would have to build in some sort of check for delivery at a higher layer (or into your application).
- use some low cost Android based device for your 3G connectivity and leverage the Google push notifications mechanism

It is worth noting that server polling typically gets very bad press as it is seems intuitively wasteful to have the client and the server constantly checking for messages, especially when the actual messages are fairly infrequent. However, underneath most push solutions there is still a pull mechanism in the background, albeit generally a very efficient one that may, for example, piggy back on other messages between the network and the mobile device and hence have minimal power and data overhead. Personally, I would say that if you do not have major concerns with battery/power or with the load polling might generate for your servers, then it is worth exploring if the simplicity benefits of a polling solution outweigh its other disadvantages.